3-uniform hypergraphs with only disjoint perfect matchings
I am searching for 3-uniform hypergraphs with only disjoint perfect matchings (i.e., every hyperedge only appears in at most one of the perfect matchings).
For example, $K_6^3$ has 10 disjoint perfect matchings, and they are all pairwise disjoint. I could also find a 9-vertex 3-uniform hypergraph that can achieve 13 perfect matchings that are pairwise disjoint.
For a general n-vertex 3-uniform hypergraph, we know that the number of disjoint perfect matchings is at most $O(n^2)$, as the maximum degree is a trivial upper bound. Can this can be improved?

For 2-uniform hypergraphs, i.e., the usual graphs, the answer is known to be 3. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/267002/graphs-with-only-disjoint-perfect-matchings/267013#267013

This is a 9-vertex hypergraph that can achieve 13:
{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
{{1, 2, 8}, {3, 6, 9}, {4, 5, 7}}
{{1, 2, 9}, {3, 5, 6}, {4, 7, 8}}
{{1, 3, 4}, {2, 7, 9}, {5, 6, 8}}
{{1, 3, 7}, {2, 4, 6}, {5, 8, 9}}
{{1, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 8}, {6, 7, 9}}
{{1, 4, 7}, {2, 6, 9}, {3, 5, 8}}
{{1, 4, 9}, {2, 6, 8}, {3, 5, 7}}
{{1, 5, 6}, {2, 4, 7}, {3, 8, 9}}
{{1, 5, 9}, {2, 4, 8}, {3, 6, 7}}
{{1, 6, 7}, {2, 3, 5}, {4, 8, 9}}
{{1, 6, 8}, {2, 5, 7}, {3, 4, 9}}
{{1, 7, 8}, {2, 5, 9}, {3, 4, 6}}
